# What is an edge using field expansion (as described in the Instagram api)?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I'm having a look through the instagram api documentation and I don't understand what they mean when they say: Fields marked with an asterisk (*) are public fields, which means they can be returned by an edge using field expansion.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Link:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-user

Section in question:

```
Permissions

A Facebook User access token with the following permissions:

pages_read_engagement
instagram_basic and any of ads_management, business_management, pages_show_list

Returnable Fields
biography*
id*
ig_id
followers_count*
follows_count
media_count*
name
profile_picture_url
username*
website*

Fields marked with an asterisk (*) are public fields, which means they can be returned by an edge 
using field expansion.
```

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#field-expansion, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/advanced#fieldexpansion

Comment: @CBroe The link's dead, can you please tell us what it said?

Comment: @MontanaBurr https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/guides/field-expansion